# Problems saving the items from a list into a xml file Android

Tags: android, xml, list

I have implemented an app capable of detecting BLE signals and show it as a list using an adapter. After showing the the BLE devices, I save the characteristics from each list into xml file. When the app detects devices, it saves perfectly; the problem I have right now is that if it hasn´t detected any signal or, saying in another way, there are no items in the list, when it tries to save it into a xml file, the app crashes and close. I tried to fix it by checking if the number of items of the list; if it is 0 it does the "else" part of the code and if it is more than 0, it saves the list as shown below. However it still causing the same problem and I don´t know what to do more.

Here is the code I use to save into a xml file:

```
public class Save {   

  /**
 * Save the last BLE List in a XML File
 */

private BleDevicesAdapter leDeviceListAdapter;

Save(BleDevicesAdapter BLEList) {

    leDeviceListAdapter = BLEList;

}


public void savedata() throws FileNotFoundException{

    String filename = "BLEDevices.xml";

    long dateutc = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long finaldateutc = 62135596800000L + dateutc;

    double frequency = 1/(0.001*SCAN_PERIOD);

    long period = 200;




    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Mis archivos");
    directory.mkdirs();
    File file= new File(directory, filename);


    if (leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(0) != null) {
        int size = leDeviceListAdapter.getCount();
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //fos= openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
            serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

            serializer.startTag("", "root");
            serializer.startTag("", "measurement");
            serializer.attribute("", "time", String.valueOf(finaldateutc));
            //serializer.attribute("", "scan period", String.valueOf(period));


            for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++) {
                BluetoothDevice devices = leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(j);
                Integer signal = leDeviceListAdapter.getRSSI(j);
                serializer.startTag("", "device");
                serializer.attribute("", "rssi", String.valueOf(signal));
                serializer.attribute("", "mac", devices.getAddress());
                serializer.attribute("", "name", devices.getName());


                serializer.endTag("", "device");

            }

            //ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            //out.writeObject(leDeviceListAdapter);
            //out.close();

            serializer.endDocument();
            serializer.flush();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, R.string.list_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //fos= openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
            serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

            serializer.startTag("", "root");
            serializer.startTag("", "measurement");
            serializer.attribute("", "time", String.valueOf(finaldateutc));
            serializer.endDocument();
            serializer.flush();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, R.string.list_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is also the log of the problem:

```
03-18 12:51:17.081: D/BluetoothAdapter(18804): stopLeScan()
03-18 12:51:17.086: D/AndroidRuntime(18804): Shutting down VM
03-18 12:51:17.086: W/dalvikvm(18804): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42027700)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.example.newblescan.adapter.BleDevicesAdapter.getDevice(BleDevicesAdapter.java:50)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.example.newblescan.DeviceScanActivity$Save.savedata(DeviceScanActivity.java:346)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.example.newblescan.DeviceScanActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DeviceScanActivity.java:131)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:630)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:200)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-18 12:51:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(18804):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 12:51:17.161: D/BluetoothAdapter(18804): stopLeScan()
03-18 12:51:17.161: D/BluetoothAdapter(18804): stopLeScan()
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem or put the right answer?? Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because of there is no data in the Array List, size is 0. What you can do is, you can check if the ArrayList is empty or not in the BleDevicesAdapter.

```
public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {

        if(leDevices == null || leDevices.size() == 0 ) {
            return null;
        }

        return leDevices.get(position);
    }
```

somthing like this. Then you can check it like the code below.

```
if (leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(0) != null)
```

Comment: thanks you were right with the solution. It occured another problem when saving the xml file because of there was no endTag but now it works perfectly. Again thanks a lot